# Deleting files containing G-d's Name / taking the host device into the bathroom

Tags: halacha, technology, jewish-books, shemos-sacred-names, bathroom

Is there any issue regarding deleting electronic files with G-d's Name in them?

Also, is there any issue with taking such a device into the bathroom?

Comment: See also: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/83/when-blogging-emailing-etc-do-i-use-god-or-g-d/86#86

Comment: A later question asked the same question better: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10777.

Comment: Why would it be different than walking onto a bathroom with Torah encoded in the memory of your brain?

Answer (score 7):

A digital representation of Hashem's name, whether it is His unique name or others, does not constitute writing. Consequently there is no issue of erasing it.

There is no prohibition against bringing a digital representation of Hashem's name into a bathroom per se, but to have it displayed visual would not be respectable (similar to how we don't wear a tallis gadol in a bathroom even though it's technically allowed). Furthermore we are not supposed to *think* about holy matters in the bathroom (except for halachos relevant to our conduct there), so it would not be appropriate to display such material in such a location.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning, but you should add that the problem with wearing the Tallis Gadol into the Beis Hakisei is that it is a garment set aside particularly for Tefillah.

Comment: Um, source?.....

Comment: This is the answer I was given by my Rabbi when I asked this question.

Comment: Most Rabbonim are makil (to erase.) There is a "shmu'ah" going around that R' Eliyashuv held it was ossur to erase. However this is very difficult to understand and no reason is given other then he holds this is a "casiva" !?!?!

Comment: +0, since you haven't provided any source.

Comment: Interesting svara but really needs some sources. Also, I don't see why you are comparing an open computer screen with Hashem's name on it to a talit gadol. Why wouldn't my smartphone I learn torah on be the same thing even when the screen is closed?