# Hashem's Name in Digital Works

Tags: halacha, text, prayer-book

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hashems name on device](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/hashems-name-on-device)

Normally there are all sorts of problems with writing Hashem's name on paper, and then erasing it. How does this apply to digital mediums (more specifically, computers & phones)?

Also, which names does this apply to? [or should that be a separate question?]

Comment: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/1186/hashems-name-on-device

http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/83/when-blogging-emailing-etc-do-i-use-god-or-g-d/86#86

Comment: @Gershon Agreed.