# What to do if you drop a sefer

Tags: halacha, minhag, jewish-books, holy-objects

Is there anything to say or do if you accidentally drop a sefer on the floor, besides kissing it and putting it back?

*not a sefer Torah, ch"v!

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13839/dropping-a-phone-siddur-or-chumash

Comment: Pick it up. [15]

Comment: Re "besides kissing": note that not everyone has the custom to kiss a dropped _sefer_.

Comment: I understand some have a custom to use a _sefer_ that's fallen, as a sign of respect for the _sefer_. I have no source for this, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mishna Brura סימן צו ס"ק ז:

" נפל ספר על הארץ ואינו יכול לכוין מותר להגביהו כשיסיים הברכה שהוא עומד בה ואי לא"ה לא יפסיק ".

It says that only if you can't keep on focus the prayer you need to pick it up immediately, but by the way we learn that you should pick it up immediately if it's not during a prayer. To kiss it is a 'Hidur'.

BTW, Sefer Hasidim says that if you drop a few books together you should pick the all and only then start kissing them one by one.

Apart from these I dont know any action that you should do.
Maybe hold books tighter :)

Hope it helps

Comment: "by the way we learn that you should pick it up immediately if it's not during a prayer" How do you see that from your quote?

Comment: because he chose a prayer situation. If he would not expect me to pick up the book even NOT during a prayer- he would not choose this situation to say that rule.

Comment: @NissimYarchi He's taking about if it's disturbing you that it's on the floor. It doesn't necessarily teach us that you have to pick it. But you're right that you have to pick it up.