# Giving a divorce (get) written on a tablet screen

Tags: technology, divorce, modern-times, legal-documents

Can a person divorce his wife by giving her a *get* written on a tablet screen?

Comment: A tablet screen is not permanent. It is erased as soon as the power is turned off

Comment: And give her the tablet? Anyway it’s eraseable which invalidates the get

Comment: @Chatzkel yes..

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible. The Rambam ([MT Gerushin 4:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/957709/jewish/Gerushin-Chapter-Four.htm)) explains why electronic "ink" on a tablet doesn't work

> **A get may be written only with a substance that leaves a permanent
> impression** - e.g., ink, sikra, kumus, kankantum or the like. If,
> however, [a get] is written with a substance that does not leave a
> permanent impression - e.g., beverages, fruit juices or the like - the
> get is void.

Since the "ink" on a tablet is not permanent, it is not appropriate to write a *get*.

Comment: It might work on a kindle according to some (not nearly all) poskim though https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7275/11532