# Downloading Torah in the bathroom

Tags: halacha, technology, shemos-sacred-names, bathroom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hashems name on device](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/hashems-name-on-device)

I know this sounds a little ridiculous, but this has actually happened to me. Let's say you are using a smartphone to download a lengthy Devar Torah, a Shi'ur in mp3 or video, or a Sefer (on Hebrewbooks.org, for example). It's taking a long time, so you open another browser or you simply put the phone in your pocket, and you forget about the fact that it's downloading. You then enter the bathroom and realize you left the download in progress and the phone is in your pocket in the bathroom. Do you have to leave the bathroom? Let's say you didn't forget. Can you go into the bathroom, knowing that this is going on?

Comment: If you go that far, you may have to say that you're never allowed to bring it into the bathroom: If it has *any* Torah on it at all, it may be comparable to a gemara which has very lengthy dedication pages

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1186. No?

Comment: @msh210 Yeah, probably. But it might be a variant.