# Is it permissible to post photos of pages of a siddur (containing YHVH) online?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, internet, shemos-sacred-names, social-media

I am planning to write a detailed blog post about the weekday Shacharit service, and I want to illustrate it with photos of pages from my ArtScroll siddur. Is this permissible, given that the pages contain the Tetragrammaton and other names for Hashem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hashems name on device](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/hashems-name-on-device)

Comment: I did explore some of those threads a little bit. I would've liked to see more sources cited, but also the specific issue of photographing a siddur feels different to me.

Comment: If there's any difference between photos and Unicode representations of the name (which I doubt there is) I think photos are _more_ likely to be acceptable because one _could_ say that the binary representation is like writing the name

Comment: why should it be forbidden?